# Convert String to BigDecimal

Tags: java

There are lots of solution for converting String to BigDecimal in Java but my question is little bit different

```
if (obj.getAmount() != null) {
    payment.setAmount(new BigDecimal(p.getAmount()));
}
```

How can I convert the above code in JDK 8..

I have tried below code but not working

```
AppCommonUtils.optional(payment.getAmount()).map(new::BigDecimal).ifPresent(txnCustomerPayment::setAmount);

public static Optional<String> optional(String value) {
   return StringUtils.isNotBlank(value) ? Optional.of(value) : Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: BigDecimal has a constructor that accepts a String. `String s = "1234"; BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(s);`

Comment: What does "Not working" mean?

Comment: `Optional#ofNullable` will work but it also hurts readability, so you would wanna stick to simple if-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few problems with your code e.g. `new::BigDecimal` is not a valid expression.

Assuming `obj.getAmount()` returns a `String` it should look like:

```
Optional.ofNullable(obj.getAmount())
    .map(BigDecimal::new)
    .ifPresent(payment::setAmount)
```